# modreg package in R studio

Tags: r

How can I install the package "modreg" in R studio. the is no such a package in CRAN. but I read this sentence somewhere:

It's one of the "base" packages, hence in the R sources:

PathToR/R/src/library/modreg

what does it mean in R studio?

Comment: From [this question and answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2010-June/034197.html) `modreg` has been integrated into the `stats` package. This means its already in R and there no need to install it. Which functions do you need?

Comment: I trying to run Regime shifts in BRODGAR software. it is base on R. But after running the R code I do recive this masseges.""Error in library(modreg) : there is no package called 'modreg'